# meta key and meta_value query in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am running a query successfully in wordpress.Query is as follows.

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms 
WHERE term_id = '12' AND term_taxonomy_id = '12' AND ID = post_id 
AND ID = object_id AND post_type = 'property' AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND meta_key = 'property_amount' AND replace( replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' ) >= 1 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY replace( replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' ) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

But I want to add one more meta_key and its value condition in above query so I changed my query to this

```
  SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms 
  WHERE term_id = '12' AND term_taxonomy_id = '12' AND ID = post_id
  AND ID = object_id AND post_type = 'property' AND post_status = 'publish' 
  AND meta_key = 'property_amount' AND replace( replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' )
>= 1
  AND meta_key="property_land_type" and meta_value IN ('L','H','C')
  GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY replace( replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' ) DESC 
  LIMIT 0, 10
```

Following line is extra in first query

```
meta_key="property_land_type" and meta_value in ('L','H','C')
```

But it is not working. How to do this.I can not write WP_Query this time as I have lots of other queries based on this query.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple meta_keys against one  column you need `IN()` for both meta_key and value like

```
meta_key IN( 'property_amount','property_land_type') 
AND meta_value IN ('L','H','C',replace( replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' ) >= 1)
```

Try this query

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM 
wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms 
WHERE term_id = '12' AND term_taxonomy_id = '12' AND ID = post_id 
AND ID = object_id AND post_type = 'property' AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND meta_key IN( 'property_amount','property_land_type') 
AND meta_value IN ('L','H','C',replace( replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' ) >= 1)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY replace( replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' ) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

**EDIT**

Try this one with join ,i have joined wp_postmeta two times for two meta_keys

```
SELECT wp.*, wpm1.meta_value AS `propert_type`,
wpm2.meta_value AS `property_amount`
FROM 
wp_posts  wp
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm1 ON (wp.ID = wpm1.post_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm2 ON (wp.ID = wpm2.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wptr ON (wp.ID = wptr.object_id)
INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` wptt ON (wptr.term_taxonomy_id = wptt.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms wpt ON (wptt.term_id = wpt.term_id)

WHERE wpt.term_id = '12' AND wptr.term_taxonomy_id = '12' 
AND  wp.post_type = 'property' AND wp.post_status = 'publish'
AND wpm1.meta_key = 'property_land_type' 
AND wpm2.meta_key = 'property_amount'
AND REPLACE( REPLACE(wpm2.meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' ) >= 1
AND wpm1.meta_value IN ('L','H','C') AND  wpm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL AND  wpm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY wp.ID ORDER BY REPLACE( REPLACE(wpm2.meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '' ) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I got one more test case where this query is not working dude. :( If I  have a record which is not having any property_land_type means it is NULL but its price is greater than 1 in that case it is also taking that record since amount > 1

Comment: It is ok but I have so many queries based on searching and sorting.So can u tell me without join means just use 2 times postmeta table.

Answer (score 0):

In your second query you have two contradicting conditions: `meta_key = 'property_amount' AND meta_key="property_land_type"`

No result satisfies both conditions