# Multiple meta key and meta value in single query (wordpress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am running a query successfully in wordpress.Query is as follows.

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms
WHERE term_id = '12'
  AND term_taxonomy_id = '12'
  AND ID = post_id
  AND ID = object_id
  AND post_type = 'property'
  AND post_status = 'publish'
  AND meta_key = 'property_amount'
  AND replace(replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '') >= 1
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY replace(replace(meta_value, ',', ''), '"', '') DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

But I want to add one more meta_key and its value condition in above query so I changed my query to this

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms
WHERE term_id = '12'
  AND term_taxonomy_id = '12'
  AND ID = post_id
  AND ID = object_id
  AND post_type = 'property'
  AND post_status = 'publish'
  AND ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_amount'
      AND wp_postmeta.meta_value) >= '1'
      AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_land_type'
      AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('H', 'C')))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

Following line is extra in first query

```
meta_key="property_land_type" and meta_value in ('L','H','C')
```

But it is not working. How to do this.I can not write WP_Query this time as I have lots of other queries based on this query.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you be more specific instead of "it is not working"? What exactly is not working?

Comment: already asked and answered here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160027/meta-key-and-meta-value-query-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Without adding your own query, try to extend the wordpress query. You can customize the following code,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'property_amount',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'property_land_type',
            'value' => 'L',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'property_amount',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'property_land_type',
            'value' => array('L','H','C'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
             echo $post_id = get_the_ID();
    endwhile;
endif;
```